# Marginpar appearing on the wrong side (using memoir)

Tags: positioning, page-breaking, memoir, marginpar

The subject line pretty much says it all: some marginal notes (beginning of the second page) do not appear on the correct side. (The question is: how can I fix this automatically?) Below is a MWE that I got from my code, where I removed as much text as possible (and replace the missing text by a vertical space).  I tried to remove some equations and the itemize environment to simplify things further, but could not get the right value of `\vspace` to still illustrate the problem.

---

*This is a partial answer to my problem ...  If I write `\strictpagecheck` before each `\marginpar` **and** if I explictly write `\marginparmargin{outer}` (which is supposed to be the default), the notes on the second page all get positioned on the correct side.  The problem is that the notes that were previously on the wrong side now partly overlap the other ones.*

---

*Commenting on an answer which was deleted by its author: I do not want the `oneside` option as this is going to be printed as a book.  Also, I tried `sidepar` and it definitely does not work: the notes on the first page are on the wrong side and some of the ones on the second overlap. Eventually, I will want to add figures as well as text in the margins.*

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}

\setstocksize{11in}{8.5in}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settypeblocksize{9.0in}{30pc}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.7in}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{1.0in}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{30pt}{26pt}
\setheaderspaces{*}{30pt}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0.2in}{1.5in}{0.2in}
\checkandfixthelayout
%

\begin{document}
Some text to get things started.
\vspace*{17cm} % to minimize the amount of text on the page.

Some text\marginpar{First note} with some notes in the margin.
Some text\marginpar{Second note} with some notes in the margin.
Some text\marginpar{Third note} with some notes in the margin.

\begin{itemize}
\item First item.  
    $$A=B$$
\item Second item.
    $$A=B$$
\end{itemize}

Yet more text with a note\marginpar{Fourth note} followed by an equation.
$$
A = B
$$

Now we can see the problem.\marginpar{This note is on the wrong side.}. 
With some more text\marginpar{And another note on the wrong side.} 
so we can perhaps start seeing what is going on.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep
the notes somewhat separate\marginpar{Note 1 on the correct side}.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep 
the notes somewhat separate\marginpar{Note 2 also}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: one single `\strictpagecheck` in the preamble and it works fine for me. Remember that you will need several runs (the feature use labels to verify pages)

Comment: No offence, but if you delete answers, then I don't think you will see particularly many people helping you.

Comment: Hmm, I see the last problem. No idea what is going on here

Comment: I've added it to my todo list, but I will not have time to work on it until easter.

Comment: @daleif I have only deleted my own answer (which I can still see).  Someone else posted a tentative answer and, when it did not solve the problem, asked that I document what I did before he deleted the answer.  I would never delete an answer written by someone else - nor downvote it as I do appreciate the time that other people put into helping.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the fact that the "wrong" `\marginpar` are in the first line after a display that ends a page. You can manually fix it by issuing `\clearpage` after the display and adding `\noindent` if you don't want an indent. With `\strictpagecheck` the second marginpar overwrites the third and fourth. :(

Comment: By adding `\usepackage{marginfix}` to the preamble, the problems with overlapping and wrong margins disappear, but now the fifth and sixth note are on the first page :-( Which leads me to the crude theory that somehow the first line after the displayed equation was considered for the first page but split off later, when the marginpars were already placed. There is some strange code for handling marginpars in `\@specialoutput`, followed by extremely involved code in `\@doclearpage`. If the line is split to the second page at this point, the marginpars are already placed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is intrinsic to LaTeX's marginpar implementation. One possible solution is as follows. This uses pdftex's `\pdfsavepos` extension, I think other newer engines have similar extensions. Also it would need to be packaged and made a bit more generic (and tested on more than this one input file). But basically the idea is that `\marginpar` *just* saves its text in a box (actually two boxes a left and right hand version) then on the *next* run, LaTeX uses information from  `\pdfsavepos` to align the margin notes at the vertical position of the callout as saved in the aux file. If it would overlap a previous one it is moved down, the positioning is done with shrinkable glue so if the margin column gets too full, the glue will shrink (so notes will move up to allow later ones to fit).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
% Adjust paperheight for more useful image


\makeatletter

\newbox\@mpbox
\global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{}


\def\savedpos#1#2#3#4{%
\begingroup
\let\@positions\relax
\expandafter\xdef\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname\relax
\else
\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname
\fi
  \@positions{#3}{#4}}%
\endgroup}

\def\marginpar#1{%
  \saveposition{mpar}%
  \global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{\unvbox\@mpbox\hbox{%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset\raggedright#1}}%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset\raggedleft#1}}%
}\break}}



\def\saveposition#1{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
  \noexpand\savedpos
    {#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\pdflastxpos}{\the\pdflastypos}}}


\def\@oddfoot{%
  \hss\thepage\hss\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\mcolumn}}
\def\@evenfoot{%
  \llap{\mcolumn\hskip\marginparsep}\hss\thepage\hss\saveposition{foot}}

\def\mcolumn{%
\saveposition{foot}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname\relax
\else
\let\@positions\origin@positions
\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname
\smash{\raise\footskip\vbox to \textheight{\hsize\marginparwidth
\hrule\@height\z@
\let\@positions\mp@positions
\csname sp@mpar-\the\c@page\endcsname
\vskip\z@\@plus\textheight
\hrule\@height\z@}}%
\fi}

\def\origin@positions#1#2{%
\@tempdima\z@
\dimen@\textheight
\advance\dimen@\headsep
\advance\dimen@ #2sp
}
\def\mp@positions#1#2{%
\setbox\tw@=\vsplit\@mpbox to \maxdimen
\setbox\tw@\vbox{%
\unvbox\tw@
\setbox\tw@\lastbox
\setbox\tw@\hbox{%
\unhbox\tw@
\ifodd\c@page
\global\setbox1\lastbox
\fi
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}}%
\@tempdimb\dimen@
\advance\@tempdimb-#2sp
\ifdim\@tempdimb<2\p@
\@tempdimb2\p@
\fi
\vskip\@tempdimb\@minus\@tempdimb
\advance\dimen@-\@tempdimb
\advance\dimen@-\ht\@ne
\advance\dimen@-\dp\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
\box\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
}

\showboxdepth=2
\showboxbreadth=50

\begin{document}


Some text to get things started.
\vspace*{14cm} % to minimize the amount of text on the page.

\begin{itemize}
\item First item.  
    $$A=B$$
\item Second item.
    $$A=B$$
\end{itemize}

Yet more text with a noteZZ\marginpar{zeroth note} followed by an equation.
\[
A = B
\]

Now we can see the problem.AA\marginpar{This is the first note. I'm making it quite long to see some overlapping with mparhack.}. 
With some more textBB\marginpar{Second note} 
so we can perhaps start seeing what is going on.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep
the notes somewhat separateCC\marginpar{Third note}.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep 
the notes somewhat separateDD\marginpar{Fourth note}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So you're not using an insertion at all for this! Are there any drawbacks with respect to the original definition?

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting problem, but turns out that is not isolated to `memoir`, `memoir` is just better at making it end in the right margin. See this example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
Some text to get hings started.
\vspace*{14.5cm} % to minimize the amount of text on the page.

\begin{itemize}
\item First item.  
    $$A=B$$
\item Second item.
    $$A=B$$
\end{itemize}

Yet more text with a note\marginpar{Fourth note} followed by an equation.
\[
A = B
\]

Now we can see the problem.AA\marginpar{This is the first note}. 
With some more textBB\marginpar{Second note} 
so we can perhaps start seeing what is going on.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep
the notes somewhat separateCC\marginpar{Third note}.
Some text added with other notes and a reasonably long sentence to keep 
the notes somewhat separateDD\marginpar{Forth note}.
\end{document}
```

I'll send this elsewhere

Comment: The overlapping problems are somewhat fixed by `\usepackage{marginfix}` but still the placement is strange.

Comment: @daleif. Out of curiosity I substituted **tufte-handout**, **tufte-book**, and **book** for the **article** class in daleif's example. Nothing else was changed. The problem did not appear in the tufte classes, but did appear in the book class.

Comment: @zun: Maybe because tufte classes use **mparhack**?