# "Underfull \vbox while \output is active", adjusting stretch/shrink does not make the error vanish

Tags: boxes, marginpar, xparse

I intend to use the sidenote package along with David Carlisle's implementation of `\marginpar` based on `\pdfsavedpos` from the answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52436/44160. I've simplified the `\sidenote` command a little, this is not the full version.

The basic idea behind the code below is to offer an alternative implementation of `\marginpar`, which uses the saved position of the marginpar, rather than using the regular `\c@page`-related macros (which don't always use the correct page number).

The code below produces an "Underfull `\vbox` while `\output` is active (badness 10000)" message, and I'm unsure where the problem lies.

What can I do to make the error go away?

PS: The code below requires two LaTeX runs to show the errors.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter


\NewDocumentCommand \sidenote { +m }
{
  \marginpar{#1}
}
%\let\sidenote\marginpar


\newbox\@mpbox
\global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{}
\def\savedpos#1#2#3#4{%
\begingroup
\let\@positions\relax
\expandafter\xdef\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname\relax
\else
\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname
\fi
  \@positions{#3}{#4}}%
\endgroup}

\def\marginpar#1{%
  \saveposition{mpar}%
  \global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{\unvbox\@mpbox\hbox{%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset#1}}%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset#1}}%
}\break}}

\def\saveposition#1{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
  \noexpand\savedpos
    {#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\pdflastxpos}{\the\pdflastypos}}}

\def\@oddfoot{%
  \hss\thepage\hss\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\mcolumn}}
\def\@evenfoot{%
  \llap{\mcolumn\hskip\marginparsep}\hss\thepage\hss\saveposition{foot}}

\def\mcolumn{%
\saveposition{foot}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname\relax
\else
\let\@positions\origin@positions
\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname
\smash{\raise\footskip\vbox to \textheight{\hsize\marginparwidth
\hrule\@height\z@
\let\@positions\mp@positions
\csname sp@mpar-\the\c@page\endcsname
\vskip\z@\@plus\textheight% not here
\hrule\@height\z@}}%
\fi}

\def\origin@positions#1#2{%
\@tempdima\z@
\dimen@\textheight
\advance\dimen@\headsep
\advance\dimen@ #2sp
}
\def\mp@positions#1#2{%
\setbox\tw@=\vsplit\@mpbox to \maxdimen
\setbox\tw@\vbox{%
\unvbox\tw@
\setbox\tw@\lastbox
\setbox\tw@\hbox{%
\unhbox\tw@
\ifodd\c@page
\global\setbox1\lastbox
\fi
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}}%
\@tempdimb\dimen@
\advance\@tempdimb-#2sp
\ifdim\@tempdimb<2\p@
\@tempdimb2\p@
\fi
\vskip\@tempdimb\@minus\@tempdimb% not here either apparently
\advance\dimen@-\@tempdimb
\advance\dimen@-\ht\@ne
\advance\dimen@-\dp\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
\box\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
}

\makeatother

% just some filler text, equations, etc.
\def\someequation{%
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+V(r)\right]\psi(r)=E\psi(r).
\end{equation}
}
\def\elementarytext{%
One two three four, united states marine core.
}
\def\sometext{%
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext\sidenote{Here is a side note with some text.}
\someequation
\elementarytext\sidenote{Here is a side note with some text.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't expect that anybody will go into that complicated code. I'll vote for closing as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the warnings (which are spurious) bother you, just turn them off:

I simplified the MWE, removing xparse definition of `\sidenote`
and added a setting of `\vbadness` to silence the warning.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}


\makeatletter



\newbox\@mpbox
\global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{}
\def\savedpos#1#2#3#4{%
\begingroup
\let\@positions\relax
\expandafter\xdef\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname\relax
\else
\csname sp@#1-#2\endcsname
\fi
  \@positions{#3}{#4}}%
\endgroup}

\long\def\marginpar#1{%
  \saveposition{mpar}%
  \global\setbox\@mpbox\vbox{\unvbox\@mpbox\hbox{%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset#1}}%
  \hbox{\parbox{\marginparwidth}{\@marginparreset#1}}%
}\break}}

\def\saveposition#1{%
\pdfsavepos\write\@auxout{%
  \noexpand\savedpos
    {#1}{\the\c@page}{\the\pdflastxpos}{\the\pdflastypos}}}

\def\@oddfoot{%
  \hss\thepage\hss\rlap{\hskip\marginparsep\mcolumn}}
\def\@evenfoot{%
  \llap{\mcolumn\hskip\marginparsep}\hss\thepage\hss\saveposition{foot}}

\def\mcolumn{%
\saveposition{foot}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname\relax
\else
\let\@positions\origin@positions
\csname sp@foot-\the\c@page\endcsname
\smash{\raise\footskip\vbox to \textheight{\hsize\marginparwidth
\hrule\@height\z@
\let\@positions\mp@positions
\csname sp@mpar-\the\c@page\endcsname
\vskip\z@\@plus\textheight% not here
\hrule\@height\z@}}%
\fi}

\def\origin@positions#1#2{%
\@tempdima\z@
\dimen@\textheight
\advance\dimen@\headsep
\advance\dimen@ #2sp
}
\def\mp@positions#1#2{%
\advance\vbadness\@M
\setbox\tw@=\vsplit\@mpbox to \maxdimen
\advance\vbadness-\@M
\setbox\tw@\vbox{%
\unvbox\tw@
\setbox\tw@\lastbox
\setbox\tw@\hbox{%
\unhbox\tw@
\ifodd\c@page
\global\setbox1\lastbox
\fi
\global\setbox1\lastbox
}}%
\@tempdimb\dimen@
\advance\@tempdimb-#2sp
\ifdim\@tempdimb<2\p@
\@tempdimb2\p@
\fi
\vskip\@tempdimb\@minus\@tempdimb% not here either apparently
\advance\dimen@-\@tempdimb
\advance\dimen@-\ht\@ne
\advance\dimen@-\dp\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
\box\@ne
\hrule\@height\z@
}

\makeatother

% just some filler text, equations, etc.
\def\someequation{%
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{\hat p^2}{2m}+V(r)\right]\psi(r)=E\psi(r).
\end{equation}
}
\def\elementarytext{%
One two three four, united states marine core.
}
\def\sometext{%
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\elementarytext\par
}

\begin{document}

\sometext

\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext
\someequation
\elementarytext\marginpar{Here is a side note with some text.}
\someequation
\elementarytext\marginpar{Here is a side note with some text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\long\def\marginpar#1{...}`

Comment: @egreg if more than one paragraph is allowed it ought to be called `\marginpars` :-) But I'll add.

Comment: The original `\marginpar` command allows multiple paragraphs.

Comment: @egreg I know !

Comment: ... so what is actually causing the error? I found another answer by @egreg in a similar question with the same workaround.... but what's actually happening here?

Comment: @1010011010 it's not an error I just stored the marginpars into a temporary box that needed to be split up and positioned once the saved coordinates are known I split with `\vsplit` which causes some warnings but they do not relate to any underfull box that is actually output, `\vbadness` is a setting that doesn't affect anything except warnings, make it bigger than 10000 and you never get warnings about underfull boxes