# On the page-breaking in \marginpar{}

Tags: marginpar

I'm probably asking for something very complex, but in my not-expert mind it seems to me that is really weird not to have smart `\marginpar` (which I really want to use as a way to typeset margin notes) command which allows to have a nice typeset with margin par on the right side of the text for `twoside` documents (I used the proposed solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49983/marginpar-appearing-on-the-wrong-side-using-memoir), the packahe `mparhack`) and at the same time the possibility of extend marginpar over multiple pages (for which I haven't  find a solution yet).

I'm actually using `book` class, because I discovered too late that `memoir` class can provide something near what I want, and I would like to keep this class as there are lot of edit I made that seems not to compile with `memoir` class.

So provided `\documentclass[twoside]{book}` how can I achieve at the same time a note on the marginpar space which breaks page when it reaches the end of it and stays on the right side of the paper in twoside documents?
I looked a lot around but did not found any solution that fit my case, how can a thing like that so under-developed?
Thanks to all that will answer!

Comment: :) sorry, I did not mean to offend anyone, I understand what you're saying, I was just wondering how nobody needed that before me, not how lazy were people for not have done this

Comment: I never saw any necessity for long notes in the margins and actually don't like such layouts. Beside this you could look at scrlayer-notecolumn in the koma-bundle.